# Formal email/letter writing : correct usage of "issue which pertains to" / "issue pertaining to" /"issue that pertains to"

Tags: word-usage

In my humble attempt at writing a classy formal letter, I am stuck with a bug in my brain .. probably due to my background of a non-native speaker of English.

I am trying to draw the reader's attention to an issue related to my mobile device causing heating issues.

I wrote the following:

> Dear Sir,
>
> I would like to draw your attention to an issue pertaining to my recently purchased XYZ mobile overheating....

**Should it be, instead:**

> I would like --"-- an issue that pertains to my recently purchased --"--

Comment: I think it is formal enough if you say "an issue **with** my recently purchased XYZ..."

Comment: 'Pertains' is howlingly archaic.